# Django ORM Filtering

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My model looks like this:

```
Person(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=32)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Note(model.Models):
    person = model.ForeignKey(Person)
    action = model.CharField(max_length=32, default='call)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = model.ForeignKey(User)
```

my view:

```
def get_working_persons(self):
    relevant_actions = ['call', 'meeting', ...]
    query = Q(action__in=relevant_note_actions) | Q(date_added__range=[fourteen_days_ago, now])
    get_current_person_notes = Note.objects.filter(query).exclude(~Q(owner=request.user)).values('owner', 'action', 'person')
```

This returns a list of notes, where each person has all the notes listed, that are  posted within the date_added__range. How do I get the last note for each person in that date range, that meets the other criterias?

Answer (score 1):

```
Note.objects.filter(query).exclude(~Q(owner=request.user)).values('owner', 'action', 'person').first()
```

will return the top object of the queryset
or

```
Note.objects.filter(query).exclude(~Q(owner=request.user)).values('owner', 'action', 'person').last()
```

will return the last object of the queryset

or latest by field name

```
 Note.objects.filter(query).exclude(~Q(owner=request.user)).values('owner', 'action', 'person').latest('field_name')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. From what I can see this will return the last object only. I would like to get the last object for each person.
So something like:
    `Select * from note
    where date_added between now AND fourteen_days_ago
    GROUP BY 'person'`

Comment: @5h3z4n have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @pawel.ad this looks like what i need! Thanks